# React fetch response missing Authorization header

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, cors, fetch-api

I have some issues with CORS using React fetch and Spring Boot.

The React application runs on localhost:3000.

The Spring Boot backend runs on localhost:3001.

My problem is when I try to logging in using using fetch with the http://localhost:3001/login url the response in javascript does not contain the Authorization token.

The authentication on backend side works.

When I open the Chrome Inspector I can see the Authorization in the Network tab at the login request only it is missing in the javascript response.

The React fetch request look like the following: In the code the const userToken = response.headers.get('Authorization'); returns "null" string instead of the token.

```
return fetch("http://localhost:3001/login",{
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email,
            password
        })
    })
    .then(
        response => {
            if(response.ok) {
                const userToken = response.headers.get('Authorization');
                return true;
            }
            // Error handling
        }
    );
```

The Spring Boot Security config is like the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, REGISTRATION_URL).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilter(// Auth Filter)
            .addFilter(// Another auth Filter)
            // this disables session creation on Spring Security
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}

@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
    return source;
}

}
```

Another thing. When I used proxy: "http://127.0.0.1:3001" in the package.json the login worked and the React code above could read Authorization header. But I don't want to use proxy.

Comment: Can you try to `curl` the Spring secrity endpoint or use Postman and add the resulting Http response to your question? A valid curl command could look like the following: `curl -i -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"email":"youremail", "password","yourpassword"}' http://localhost:3001/login`

Comment: You need to have your Spring code send the Access-Control-Expose-Headers response header with Authorization in its value. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Comment: Thank you! This was the solution to add the Access-Control-Expose-Headers response header and needed to allow incomming request types GET, POST, OPTIONS and request headers to work with other requests.